# Problem with "react-native-vector-icons" in React native

Tags: react-native

I install this library :

```
npm install react-native-vector-icons
```

and link it

```
react native link
```

and i import it to my project

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
```

then i use it in render part of the component like this :

```
<Icon name={'ios-person-outline'} />
```

But when i run the android app there is no error but the icon is a qustion icon 
eny body has idea ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I used to have similar issues when I started with react-native-vector-icons until I got to understand the different type components.

```
type="AntDesign"

type="Entypo"

type="FontAwesome"

type="FontAwesome5"

type="FontAwesome5Brands"

type="Foundation"

type="Ionicons"

type="MaterialCommunityIcons"

type="MaterialIcons"

type="SimpleLineIcons"

type="Octicons"
```

etc...

Icon name "person-outline" can be found under "MaterialIcons" on "https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/", so we can do;

```
<Icon name='person-outline' type="MaterialIcons" />
```

Hope this explanation helps.

NOTE: Make sure you take the initial steps like;

```
npm install react-native-vector-icons --save
```

AND

```
react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

Comment: what is your imported statement? also, will it work with an expo-managed project?

Comment: @MohitPatil You can directly import from react-native-vector-icons. Like:    
  import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons';

Comment: It is not working with `import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons;`! (getting render error)

Comment: Can you point to its documentation?

Answer (score 2):

**react-native-vector-icons** have a lot of 'types' for the icons, you can see them here: https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/

You should specify the type of the icon on your import or when you are using them in your code. For example:

```
import SimpleIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons';
```

The code above will import only the SimpleLineIcons, then you can use them like this:

```
<SimpleIcon name="user" color="rgba(110, 120, 170, 1)" size={25} />
```

Or, you can import them like this:

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/'
```

And then, use it like this (specifying the type):

```
<Icon
  name='check'
  color='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)'
  size={25}
  type="entypo"
/>
```

Comment: Hey, want to get the name of an icon in my State like this, name={`ios-${this.state.favIcon}`}, but doesn't work anymore, any idea?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Kivul's answer. Whenever you want to use the react-native-vector-icons. Instead of specifying the type on the component, just simply import the type of icon the name belongs to and use it. Below is an example of this:

```
import { 
   Ionicons, 
   Entypo, 
   MaterialCommunityIcons, 
   FontAwesome 
} from '@expo/vector-icons/';
```

Then in your render method, return any of the components, and pass in the name of the icon.

[pick the name from https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRefJ.png)

```
<FontAwesome 
  name={'money'} 
 ... 
 />
```

Same with the others, find the name, then the component it belongs to, import it and add the name to it.

I hope this helps?

Comment: This works for Expo not for bare react native project

Answer (score 1):

There can be two things, either you might not be writing the correct name of the icon or that specific icon is not being found via the library. Its a very common problem with the library. Try changing the icon name with some other more common icon and it will work. Its not actually issue. Please check and see if that helps. Thanks.

Also you should change the import statement of Ionicons  to `/Ionicons`. I am not sure how is that with `\` even working but hope my solution helps.

Have just tried to use the `ios-person-outline`, and as expected it didn't work, but `ios-person` did. Its a very common issue with the library that it doesnt honor the outline and other kinds of icons, it also happens with the material icon when trying to use solid or some other type of icon.

Comment: the icon name was wrong
how can i find names of the icon ?

Comment: @MoHammaDReZaDehGhani in my experience, the library doesnt ever support any `outline`, `solid` or other kind of stuff on any icon. It just have to be the name of the icon. 
Regarding finding the icon, you should probably ask the deisgner to custom make it for the app or find it from the various sources which the library supports. like `entypo`, `ionicons`, `materialicons`, etc.

Comment: all icon name can be found in node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/glyphmaps/*.json

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: Install react-native-element:**

```
npm install react-native-elements --save
```

**Steps 2: Install react-native-vector-icons Install from npm**

```
npm install react-native-vector-icons --save
```

**Link It**

```
react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

**Step 1: After that you can use it on your page by**

```
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
```

**Step 2:**

```
<Icon name="md-beer" type="ionicon" color="#887700" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the next line to your /app/build.gradle

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```